# Is it allowed to have any logging on Android Public release?

Tags: java, android, logging, google-play

Is it allowed to have any logging on Android Public release to Play store?

According to their [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html) usage of Android specific [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) is not allowed. What about [java.util.Logging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)? Is it allowed or does the prohibition extend to these loggings, too?

**Part of the documentation:** *(Interesting parts highlighted)*

> **Turn off logging and debugging**
>
> Make sure you deactivate logging and disable the debugging option before you build your application for release. **You can deactivate logging by removing calls to Log methods in your source files.** You can disable debugging by removing the android:debuggable attribute from the  tag in your manifest file, or by setting the android:debuggable attribute to false in your manifest file. Also, remove any log files or static test files that were created in your project.
>
> Also, you should remove all Debug tracing calls that you added to your code, such as startMethodTracing() and stopMethodTracing() method calls.

Anybody have experience of logging on Android apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only relevant to removing excessive and development-related logging. There is not a strict ban and it is useful to have some very limited logging as application crash reports provide the Log Cat to you.